# IIS 7 share bin folder between multiple web applications

Tags: iis-7, network-share, asp.net-mvc

Maybe this question is more appropriate to stackoverflow, not sure:

What is the best practice for sharing the assemblies of a bin folder across multiple ASP.net websites in IIS 7?

I've got several sites, each with slightly different HTML front ends, but all with the same middle tier logic and DB.  I don't want to redploy the same dlls to each of the many site's bin folders everytime I make a change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could deploy your common assemblies to the [Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx) (GAC).